# Changing Bandwidth Allocation of a traffic path via OpenFlow

Tags: sdn, openflow, pox

Is it possible to change the bandwidth allocation for a certain path reactively in `SDN`? Suppose in my `POX` controller I create a path `S -> A -> B -> D` (`S` is a client, `D` is a web server). Can I change the bandwidth of this path in realtime using `POX` and `OpenFlow`? If so, I don't see how to do that via flow table in each `switch` along this path.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Which version of POX do you use?

Comment: @SotirisTsartsaris Thank you very much for your answer. I am using the  Git branch (carp) in my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POX uses Openflow 1.0. That said you can not directly change the bandwidth that has been setup in the Mininet topology (assume you use minitet). In order to setup a bandwidth control you have to mess up with Queues (Section 5.3.4 Queue Configuration Messages in the [Openflow 1.0 specs](http://archive.openflow.org/documents/openflow-spec-v1.0.0.pdf)).

The idea is simple to get, but a bit difficult to implement. Let's say you have a client A that makes requests to Client B. To your QoS aggrement you said that the connection between those two clients can not be less than 3MB/s (24mbits/s). 
You have to keep record of the bandwidth in this route (A->B). Based on the current load, and the minimum required by this 2 clients you have to queue up and down the requests in the Openflow enabled switches so that they get served on time or delayed.

To measure bandwitdh with POX please refer to [this link](https://github.com/tsartsaris/pythess-SDN/blob/master/pythess.py) line 84. For a verified solution on bandwidth QoS etc. please read about [FlowVisor](http://archive.openflow.org/downloads/technicalreports/openflow-tr-2009-1-flowvisor.pdf) that uses queues and slices.

Comment: Thank you very much. So the solution of this is via queuing the other traffic when the throughput is dropped. 
(1) I believe `OF 1.3+` introduced `meters`, do you think using meters is a lot easier than queuing?
(2) If so, can you suggest me another controller that is close from POX and support `OF 1.3+` so that I can use meters? 
(3) Do you think POX would get support `OF 1.3+` any sooner?

Comment: Oh! Great! I haven't seen this controller before. You are saying this is the closest one to POX? The reason why I don't want to change to floodlight, for example, is because I am familiar POX python approach so I hope Ryu won't be that far.